# Xdebug in PhpStorm cannot locate extended classes

Tags: codeigniter, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a CodeIgniter project which has some errors and I am trying to debug it. However, when I start debugging the debugger exits because `MY_Controller` which is extended by all controllers was not found.

The error on the console is like this:

> Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found.

`MY_Controller` is in the application core folder and extends the `CI_Controller`. Why cant the debugger locate this class?

Apparently without solving this I cant debug my files. Otherwise the error does not pop up when I run the project without the debugger listening. I am using xdebug and PhpStorm.

Comment: AFAIK this has nothing to do with xdebug (the reason for the error). First of all -- how do you debug it? So far it sounds like you are trying to debug your controller class **directly**, which is wrong -- you need to debug whole app. Right now it looks like the core of CodeIgniter is not loaded and therefore PHP (yes, PHP and not xdebug) cannot find the necessary class. I suggest to check some PHP debug manuals and debug it as web app and not as individual script. You can start here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: first of all I am quite new to debugging and I have been trying to debug a single script other than the whole project. Thank you for the answer